# How do I prevent Firebase Cloud Messaging from sending duplicate notifications

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging, progressive-web-apps

I'm using Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) to send reminder notifications for a PWA to android devices, the reminders are send at the correct time, however it is sending the notification 2 times in different formats (screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hywao.jpg).

I'm using Firebase functions to trigger the notification at the correct time. However the function I wrote with NodeJS doesn't seem to be the problem, since when I'm testing a FCM campaign in the console, I'm also receiving 2 notifications instead of 1.

The functions log only seem to send 1 notification.

```
if (new Date(currentTime).getHours() === new Date(reminderDate).getHours() && new Date(currentTime).getMinutes() === new Date(reminderDate).getMinutes()) {
                    const devicetoken = user.data().deviceToken;
                    const userId = user.id;

                    console.log(`Sending intake notification to user ${userId}`);

                    const payload = {
                        notification: {
                            title: "Erinnerung Tabletteneinnahme",
                            body: "test",
                            image: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/lilly-c51cf.appspot.com/o/FCMImages%2Ficon.png?alt=media&token=94b9d38c-c141-4aa9-8cb5-1cf70eb165ca",
                            icon: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/lilly-c51cf.appspot.com/o/FCMImages%2Ficon.png?alt=media&token=94b9d38c-c141-4aa9-8cb5-1cf70eb165ca",
                        }
                    };

                    admin.messaging().sendToDevice(devicetoken, payload);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

For the [message payload](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/messaging_.messagepayload) if you send the `notification` attribute the firebase messaging sw will automatically display the notification.

If you use the `data` attribute instead then the firebase messaging sw won't display the notification automatically, you have all the control.

Basically change the way you build your payload to something like this:

```
      // Notification details.
      const payload = {
        data: {
          title: 'title',
          body: `a body thingy`,
          icon: 'http://someicon.com/someicon.png',
        },
      };

      // Send to device
      await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(devicetoken, payload);
```

P.S: it seems `sendToDevice()` is now [deprecated](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.messaging.messaging#messagingsendtodevice)

Comment: Be sure to not rely on "data" notification object, because it's a silent notification with low interest and iOS and android may not display your notification.

You should not rely on data only messages to be delivered. They should only be used to support your application's non-critical functionality, e.g. pre-fetching data so the next time the user opens your app the data is ready to be displayed and if the message never gets delivered then your app still functions and fetches data on open. (cf: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/usage/#low-priority-messages)